# How can I convert number like 0x00000026 to number like 38

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a stored procedure in SQL, when I run this stored procedure, I get the number 38, but when I try to run it in C#, I get the number `0x00000026`.

How can I convert it to a "normal" number?

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Registration 
    (@UserName nvarchar(50), 
     @Password nvarchar(9), 
     @FirstName nvarchar(50),
     @LastName nvarchar(50), 
     @EmailAddress nvarchar(50),
     @BDate date, 
     @IdentityNumber nvarchar(50), 
     @RoleID int)
AS
   IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Users WHERE UserName =@UserName) = 1
   BEGIN
       RETURN -1 
   END ELSE
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Users(UserName, Password, FirstName, LastName, Email, IdentityNumber, BirthDate, RoleID)
       VALUES(@UserName, @Password, @FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @IdentityNumber, @BDate, @RoleID)

       RETURN  Cast(@@IDENTITY as INT)
   END
```

and the data access layer code:

```
User test1 = DB.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "223321").ToList();

var test2 = from users in DB.Users
            where users.UserName == "223321"
            select new
                    {
                        users.UserName,
                        users.UserID
                    };
```

Comment: what is the type of the object `UserID`?

Comment: can you add sample data for IdentityNumber ?

Comment: Right click inside Locals window and make sure "Hexadecimal Display" option is unchecked.

Comment: The type of UserID is INT and the type of identityNumber is STRING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch window allows you to view the variables values in Hex Mode.
 This is very simple features, Just Right Click on Watch window and unselect Hexadecimal Display.

[image]

So Click To unselect Hexadecimal Display option for output -'38'